# Navigation Drawer Activity does not generate in android studio 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create a navigation drawer activity by right click on package->New->Activity->Navigation Drawer Activity but activity does not create.
String resource and activity attribute in manifest generated but activity file doesn't.

**Update:**
I create new project and I could create new Navigation Drawer Activity but when I remove all files related to that (including Activity, layout files, resources, etc...) I can't create again.

**Update2:**
I didn't remove drawable files, after delete I could create new Navigation Activity.

It was a crazy bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with Android Studio 4.1.1 and everything worked fine for me. Please select "Android" from top-left.

[image: Check this screenshot]

Comment: It is not generated

Comment: Android Studio 4.1.1 - Create Navigation Drawer Activity Not Working

Answer (score 0):

First of all, select "Android" from the top left corner.

[image: Select android]

Next right click your folder that is in the java folder (see screenshot).

To add the activity select New > Activity > Navigation Drawer Activity.

[image: Add activity]